# Use calculus to set up an integral for the volume of the bagel using washer method

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

A bagel is obtained by revolving a circle of radius  $ \ \frac{3}{4}  \ $ around the y-axis centered at point  $ \ (1,0) \ $. The equation of the circle is  $ \ (x-1)^2 + y^2 = (3/4)^2 \ $.

Use calculus to set up an integral for the volume of the bagel using washer method.

**Answer:**

[image]

Let  $ \  V=volume \ $ , then using washer method

$V= \int_{-\frac{3}{4}}^{\frac{3}{4}} \pi (R^2-r^2) dy \\  $

where $ \ R=outer \ \ radius \ $ and $ \ r=inner \ \ radius \ $

But what would be inner radius and outer radius?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $a=1$ be the radius of the "soul" of the bagel, and $b={3\over4}$ be the radius of the meridian circle. Your formula for the volume is basically correct, but you should clearly exhibit that the outer and inner radii of the washers depend on $y$:
$$V=\pi\int_{-b}^b \bigl(R^2(y)-r^2(y)\bigr)\>dy\ .$$
Now from the figure we can deduce that
$$R(y)=a+\sqrt{b^2-y^2},\quad r(y)=a-\sqrt{b^2-y^2}\qquad(-b\leq y\leq b)\ .$$
It follows that
$$R^2(y)-r^2(y)=4a\sqrt{b^2-y^2}\ ,$$
so that
$$V=4a\pi\int_{-b}^b\sqrt{b^2-y^2}\>dy\ ,$$
which I may leave to you.

Comment: I got it. Thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

> $$\int_{-3/4}^{3/4} \pi x^2 dy$$

That's a setup for a disk method, not a washer method.
You need to explicitly indicate the "hole",
not just a single radius.

Since you don't have enough symbols in the problem statement to write the formulas you need, you will have to use some words to define new symbols.

> $$\pi \int_{-3/4}^{3/4} \left( 1\pm \sqrt{\left(\frac34\right)^2-y^2} \right) dy$$

What does that even mean? Does it mean there are two possible answers, one in the $+$ case and one in the $-$ case?

Also, it looks like you forgot about the $2$ in $x^2$ when you substituted $x.$

Comment: Yes . It is $ (x-1)^2+y^2=(3/4)^2 \ $.

Comment: How to set up the volume integral?

Comment: Review the washer method. It can be formulated in slightly different ways so it's probably better to look in your textbook or notes than to ask me. Usually there is at least an inner radius and an outer radius.

Comment: I have added the graph into my answer part. As you said that my formula was wrong . Now can you just look the answer again?